# Using wilcox.test with large sample size

Tags: r, statistics

I'm working with a dataset with around 2,500 observations, and I wanted to know whether it's appropriate to do a Wilcoxon test on a dataset with more than 30 observations.

I ran a Shapiro-Wilk normality test on my dataframe, and it looks like the data are not normally distributed (see below). Given that, is it appropriate to run a Wilcoxon test? I'm unclear whether the Wilcoxon test is more-so reserved for smaller sample sizes.

```r
shapiro.test(df$manu_emp)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  df$manu_emp
W = 0.25801, p-value < 0.00000000000000022

wilcox.test(manu_emp ~ i_flag, data = df)

Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  df$manu_emp by i_flag
W = 707510, p-value = 0.000006872
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: When you have a large sample size (> 40) the means you want to compare will be normally distributed even if your data is not (Central Limit Theorem). So you can use both t-test and wilcoxon test.

Comment: Thanks. What do you make of the fact that the t-test yields insignificant results, but the wilcoxon test yields yields highly significant results?